# Trying to fetch data automatically when user clicks on a particular tab in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to fetch data from MySQL in android using php script,I have tested the php script using postman, and it response back with the data but my android coding doesn't seems well neither I am getting any error in logcat file. Here is code

```
public class personal_information extends Fragment {
    private TextView textViewResult;
    private ProgressDialog loading;
    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private String uniqueId;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.personal_information,container,false);
        textViewResult = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personal_info);
        db = SQLiteHandler.getInstance(getContext());
        //Fetching uniqueID
        HashMap<String,String> user = db.getUserDetails();
        uniqueId = user.get("uid");
        phone = user.get("phone");
        email = user.get("email");
        displayData();
        //Return the layout file after inflating
        return view;
    }
    private void displayData(){
        String stringRetrieve = "Retrieve values";
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(),"Loading data ...","",false,false);
        loading.setCancelable(true);
        String url = AppConfig.URL_DisplayPersonalInformation+uniqueId;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                loading.dismiss();
                showJSON(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        //Adding request to queue.
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest,stringRetrieve);
    }

    private void showJSON(String response) {
        String name = "";
        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(AppConfig.JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject personalData = result.getJSONObject(0);
            name = personalData.getString(AppConfig.first_name)+" "+personalData.getString(AppConfig.last_name);
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        textViewResult.setText("Name:\t"+name+"\nPhone:\t" +phone+ "\nEmail:\t"+ email);
    }
}
```

This is AppController file from which I am trying to make a request queue.

```
public class AppController extends MultiDexApplication {
    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static AppController mInstance;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me ?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using volley library? You need to call `addToRequestQueue` after creating the request

Comment: Yes I am using volley library.

Comment: First, you need to [setup a request queue](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html) and then [call](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) `addToRequestQueue`

Comment: Thank you I get it I just forgot to call addToRequestQueue. I have written a class file to set up the request queue.

Comment: @BornToCode I couldn't fix it I have updated my code Can you check it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are using Volley networking library.

1. First, you need to [setup a request queue](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html).
2. **Start the request queue:** `mRequestQueue.start()`.
3. Create your request. You've created it actually. But why don't you use `JsonObjectRequest`, you are about to parse it as JSON anyway. Although `StringRequest` can also be used, but `JsonObjectRequest` is there for you.

   ```
   JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest
       (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

       @Override
       public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
           // do something with response
       }
   }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           // handle error
       }
   });
   ```
4. Add it to request queue: `addToRequestQueue(...)`.

**Additional tips:**

- Don't use class name like `personal_information`, it is a convention to use camel case like `PersonalInformation`, or `PersonalInformationFragment` is better because it is a fragment.
- Don't do database query on main thread (this is out of topic of this question anyway).

Comment: Thanks man !! will check it but can you tell me when to use JSONObjectRequest and StringRequest ?

Comment: @luke Use `StringRequest` for general needs, i.e. you need the raw string, use `JsonObjectRequest` if you want Volley to parse it to JSONObject directly.